# Check if last two digits are alphabetic

Tags: sql, regex, plsql, substring

I have a column in a table with the following values:

**part**

```
1000-001-2211 

1000-001-2211AA

1000-001-2211AB

1000-001-2211AQ

1000-001-2211BI
```

I need to specially display the last two characters of each value if they are not numeric. For example, my expected output should be like this:

**part | last_two_char**

```
1000-001-2211   |         

1000-001-2211AA | AA

1000-001-2211AB | AB

1000-001-2211AQ | AQ

1000-001-2211BI | BI
```

How can get this output using a SQL query?

Comment: Have you tried where clause: WHERE columnname LIKE '%[a-z][a-z]'?

Comment: One of the things that really helps us to help you is to include what you've tried, and some sample code can't hurt.

Comment: @Zahoor you can use ISNUMERIC

Comment: Do you still need non-alpha matches to appear in the results, just without the 'last-two-char' bit?

Comment: I only need to display alphabat in the output

Answer (score 2):

```
with tab as ( select '1000-001-2211AB' col1 from dual 
 union 
select '1000-001-2211' col1 from dual )
select   REGEXP_SUBSTR( col1 ,'([[:alpha:]]{2})$') last2_alpha_char  from tab;
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways by using  `SUBSTR` , `INSTR` and `TO_NUMBER`. Since you tagged `PLSQL`.

This works. can you try this out?

First create a `function` to validate the string passed as a parameter.

```
  CREATE or replace FUNCTION is_number (p_string IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN varchar2
    IS
    v_new_num varchar2(2000);
  BEGIN
    v_new_num := TO_NUMBER(p_string);
    RETURN NULL;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
    RETURN p_string;
  END is_number;

-- function created
```

Then use any one of below queries to get desired output:

```
  select part,check_part,(part ||' | ' ||  req_part) As Final_part from
        (
        select part,(substr(part,-2,instr(part,'-',1,1) ) ) as check_part,
        IS_NUMBER( (substr(part,-2,instr(part,'-',1,1) ) )) as req_part
         -- calling IS_NUMBER function
        from parts
        ) parts;

           -- OR

  select part,check_part,(part ||' | ' ||  req_part) As Final_part from
        (
        select part,substr(part,-2,2) as check_part,
        IS_NUMBER(substr(part,-2,2)) as req_part
         -- calling IS_NUMBER function
        from parts
        ) parts;
```

**Output:**

```
    PART       CHECK_PART      FINAL_PART
1000-001-2211     11        1000-001-2211 | 
1000-001-2211AA   AA        1000-001-2211AA | AA
1000-001-2211AB   AB        1000-001-2211AB | AB
1000-001-2211AQ   AQ        1000-001-2211AQ | AQ
1000-001-2211BI   BI        1000-001-2211BI | BI
```

**Test Screenshot:**

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

You can try these simple ones using `REGEXP_LIKE`

Using `SUBSTR` , `INSTR` with `REGEXP_LIKE`

```
Select part || ' | '   || NULL as FINAL_PART
from parts -- to check number
where NOT REGEXP_LIKE ( (substr(part,-2,instr(part,'-',1,1) ) ), '[a-zA-Z]') 
UNION 
Select part || ' | '   || (substr(part,-2,instr(part,'-',1,1) ) ) 
from parts -- to check aplhabets
where  REGEXP_LIKE ( (substr(part,-2,instr(part,'-',1,1) ) ), '[a-zA-Z]') ;
```

Using just `SUBSTR`with `REGEXP_LIKE`

```
Select part || ' | '   || NULL as FINAL_PART
from parts -- to check number
where NOT REGEXP_LIKE( substr(part,-2,2), '[a-zA-Z]') 
UNION 
Select part || ' | '   || substr(part,-2,2) 
from parts -- to check aplhabets
where  REGEXP_LIKE( substr(part,-2,2) , '[a-zA-Z]' ) ;
```

**Output:**

[image: output tested]

Answer (score 1):

Below Query will help you to fetch the required result :

Lets Create the below table :

```
CREATE TABLE chartable( col1 Varchar2(200));
```

Lets insert the values into it :

```
insert into chartable values('1000-001-2211BI');
insert into chartable values('1000-001-2211AQ');
insert into chartable values('1000-001-2211AB');
insert into chartable values('1000-001-2211');
insert into chartable values('1000-001-2211AA');

COMMIT;
```

Below Query fetches you the required result :

```
select out.col1 || '|' || ( select substr(col1,-2,2) from chartable ins 
      where ins.col1 = out.col1 AND 
            regexp_like( (substr(col1,-2,2)) , '[A-Za-z]{2}' ) ) as part 
FROM chartable out;
```

Result :

```
part
1000-001-2211|
1000-001-2211AA|AA
1000-001-2211AB|AB
1000-001-2211AQ|AQ
1000-001-2211BI|BI
```

Here, [SUBSTR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) funstion will help you to fetch the last two characters.

Then, we are using [REGEXP_LIKE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php) function to check wheather the last two charcters are CHARCACTER.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Use the `RIGHT` function to select the letters from the right in a column. Use `WHERE` to shortlist the values.

`SELECT RIGHT(column_name, 2) FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%[a-z][a-z]'`

Comment: Here is my query 

SELECT BOM_HEADER
       ,SAP_CAGE_CD
       ,SUBSTR(BOM_HEADER,-2) AS CONFIG
  FROM temp_sap_boms_list_mma_ct4 A
       ,TBITEM B
       ,TBPART P
 WHERE     A.ITEM(+) = B.ITEM
       AND P.ITEM = A.ITEM
       AND BOM_HEADER LIKE '022489-054-03%';


And i am getting the following output

Bom_header           code        config
022489-054-03 0 03
022489-054-03AM 99167 AM
022489-054-03AQ 99167 AQ
022489-054-03AU 99167 AU
022489-054-03AY 99167 AY
022489-054-03BI 99167 BI

Comment: ORA-00904: "RIGHT": invalid identifier

Comment: Oracle does not supply a `RIGHT` or `LEFT` function. Use `SUBSTR` instead. `RIGHT` is equivalent to `SUBSTR(str, -2)` (to get the last two characters of the string. `LEFT` is equivalent to `SUBSTR(str, 1, 2)` (to get the first two characters of the string).